# When to use is_home() vs is_front_page()?

Tags: theme-development, homepage, frontpage, customization

I've found that `is_front_page` appears to return true when I'm viewing the home page and have a single sticky post assigned there.

It also returns true when I've assigned a page as the static front page via *Settings > Reading*.

Why would I ever want to use `is_home()`?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`is_front_page()` returns true if the user is on the page or page of posts that is set to the front page on *Settings->Reading->Your homepage* displays

So if you set `about us` as the front page then this conditional will only be true if showing the *about us* page.

`is_home()` return true when on the posts list page, This is usually the page that shows the latest 10 posts.

If the settings under *Your homepage displays* are left at default then the home page will return true for both `is_front_page()` and `is_home()`

An example of using `is_home()`:

- You have set your posts page to a page called *News*.
- A user navigates there and in the header you want to show additional navigation
- You could use `is_home()` to do this.

Comment: Exactly. I differentiate as follows: **`is_front_page()`** returns true when viewing the **Site Front Page** (whether displaying the blog posts index or a static page), while **`is_home()`** returns true when viewing the **Blog Posts Index** (whether displayed on the front page or on a static page).

Comment: Perhaps time for an alias e.g. `is_post_index` or something? Another ridiculous example of WP's obsessive backwards compatibility actually hurting usability.

Answer (score 5):

I've discovered that `is_home()` and `is_front_page()` don't deliver what's expected for multisites. My workaround using built in PHP goodies:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') {
    // you must be on the home page
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, this approach will *not* work for WP instances installed in subdirectories of the web root. Use at your discretion.

Comment: Please elaborate on how it doesn't deliver what's expected.

Comment: On a multi-site main site if you use any form of `is_home()` or `is_front_page()` on a static or blog frontpage the functions will both return false.

Comment: I just tested both conditions on a multisite environment and both returned true when I visited the respective `/` pages.

Comment: I am using the wordpress VVV box with the multisite plugin : https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/vvv-multisite  perhaps there's something misconfigured on it? Regardless just leaving an answer for a workaround if anyone comes along with a similar situation.

Comment: You're code is almost perfect, the only thing is: What if WP is installed in a subdirectory, for example /blog or /wordpress. Than this will be useless.

Comment: @RemziCavdar that's true. I'll edit my answer. Unfortunately due to the many ways you can host WP, you run into many problems.

Comment: @DylanPierce I have also given you a thumbs up. Brady's answer is more bulletproof. I think vragant is setting up your test environment wrong because both is_front_page() and is_home() should work

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use `is_home()` when you want to check if the user is viewing your list of blog posts (usually set to display 10 posts per page). If you have a `home.php` file in your theme, that will be displayed when the `is_home()` condition is true.

The following can possibly remove some confusion as well: when `is_front_page()` and `is_home()` conditions, *both* are true, the template `front-page.php` will be used instead of `home.php`.

Answer (score 0):

- You visit a frontpage that is a blog homepage => is_front_page() = **TRUE** && is_home() = **TRUE**
- You visit a front page that is a static page => is_front_page() = **TRUE**
  && is_home() = **FALSE**
- You visit the blog homepage but your front page is a static page => is_front_page() = **FALSE** && is_home() = **TRUE** (Also TRUE when reaching paginated pages)

References for definitions:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/