# Strange Behaviour with is_home()

Tags: templates, template-tags

I'm having an odd issue, although I can understand why it works like this I do need to find a way around it.

I have used the the request filter to modify the query for the home/index page to select for a post type other than 'post'

The result of this is that is_home() is returning false in the index.php template.  If I disable the filter then is_home() goes back to returning true.

Anyway to force the is_home() to return true? or another way to approach this?

Thanks, Stewart.

Comment: Is this related? [When to use is_home() vs is_front_page()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/30385/12615)

Comment: @brasofilo unfortunately no.  I haven't changed the page that is acting as the home or the front page within the Admin Panel, I have just modified the query it uses. Therefore in this case both is_home() and is_front_page() should return true but neither do.

Comment: I see... so, it'd be better if you published your code...

Comment: Please provide us with at least the function and the filter you are using.

Answer (score 0):

From look at the code the following logic happens in your case:

- query is for one post type that has archive
- `is_post_type_archive` gets set to `true`
- `is_archive` gets set to `true`
- `is_home` gets set to `false` since it is seen as archive

I am not sure about all implications without extensive testing, but probably approaches are either:

1. artificially set `is_home` to `true` under those circumstances
2. ignore failing `is_home()` and use different conditional