# wp_dequeue_script not working in my plugin

Tags: jquery, wp-admin

There is a theme my client is using. It enqueues many scripts in the admin area of WordPress. I'd like to dequeue these so that my plugin works properly.

Commenting out this code `wp_enqueue_script( "ocmx-jquery", get_template_directory_uri()."/scripts/ocmx.js", array( "jquery" ) );`
 makes my plugin work properly. So rather than edit their code, I want to add the following to my plugin `wp_dequeue_script( 'ocmx-jquery' );`. I've added that, and it's as if I never did.

Is there a better way to tell the theme's JS not to load in my plugins settings page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve a conflict between a plugin and a theme?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77772/how-to-solve-a-conflict-between-a-plugin-and-a-theme)

Comment: I tried the solution from that page, and it didn't work. The page still functioned as though I didn't have the code in place.

Comment: @Branndon You'll have to use the appropriate hooks. `admin_head`, `admin_print_scripts`, `admin_enqueue_scripts`, etc. Please show us in an [edit] how exactly your tried to get rid of that script. What you _should_ as well do is notifying those guys who developed that theme that it's complete _crap!_ to do that.

Comment: Make sure you use exactly the same handle as whats used when its enqueued

Answer (score 7):

`wp_enqueue_script()` also registers the script. So, you'll also need to de-register it first. This code should work depending on how and where the script is enqueued.

```
function my_dequeue() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'ocmx-jquery' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'ocmx-jquery' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_dequeue', 10 );
```

You might also need to play with the priority of the action.

Comment: you don't need both, dequeueing the script is enough. you only need to deregister a script if you want to register your own with the same handle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dequeue after the other script has been enqueued. That probably means hooking into `wp-enqueue_scripts`.

```
add_action(
  'wp_enqueue_scripts',
  function() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'ocmx-jquery' );
  }
);
```

Or a version for an older PHP:

```
function dequeue_ocmx_jquery() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'ocmx-jquery' );
}
add_action(
  'wp_enqueue_scripts',
  'dequeue_ocmx_jquery'
);
```

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work. It's at the top of my options page, and now the page won't even load. If I remove this code, the page loads again.

Comment: This should not really go at the top of your options page. Try the other version

Comment: Thanks @s_ha_dum the second didn't work either. I didn't want to dequeue their script globally, only on my settings page. That's why I put it in my options page code. If I just put the code in the main admin area, it would stop their code from running anywhere, and I didn't want to do that.

Comment: Try `admin_enqueue_scripts` instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`. I didn't realize this was a backend problem. However, depending on where that plugin has its code, you may not be able to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script

Have a look especially at the bottom of the page, i think this is what you want : "Admin: admin_enqueue_scripts, admin_print_scripts, admin_print_styles"

Comment: Please explain how to use `wp_dequeue_script()` and what exactly those hooks do and how to use them. Please also care a bit about the formatting of your question. Hint: The WYSIWYG editor got a `(?)` help link and something to format links and code segments. Have fun on the site :)