# If its not frontpage

Tags: homepage

Could somebody please tell me how to write

```
<?php if (in_category( array(10,11,12,13,14,15,18,19,20) )) { ?>
```

and if its not frontpage ?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224592/if-is-home-is-front-page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have the WordPress function is_front_page() that you need to invert with "!" .

```
if(!is_front_page() && in_category( array(10,11,12,13,14,15,18,19,20) ))
```