# How to check if the current page is at a specified path in the URL?

Tags: php, pages, urls, conditional-content, recent-posts

I have a page marked as the Posts page that lists most recent blog posts.

It is at path `/blog`.

I want to know when the user is on this page so that I can display a list of categories of blog posts at the beginning of the page. I already did this in singular.php and in the rest of the cases in `index.php`.

For me is_home() returns true when on the landing page. And I use its behavior in index.php.

I tried a little to use this but it does not work:

```php
get_page_by_path('/blog') == get_post()
```

So my current code is:

```php
if (!is_home() || get_page_by_path('/blog') == get_post()) {
    get_template_part('template-parts/blog-categories');
}
```

and in the /blog page the blog categories are not shown. I am sure it is because of this condition in the if above.

## Update 1

This condition does not work:

```php
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] === '/blog'
```

because it is not `/blog`, but `index.php` (behavior build through `.htaccess` I guess).

## Update 2

[image: screenshot]

Translated: Blog - Articles Page

This is not considered front page.

## Update 3

[image: screenshot]

From this screenshot I think that home is Start (LP) and Blog is Posts page. Because of this I do not get why the is_front_page call is there:

```php
if (!is_front_page() && is_home() || is_archive()) {
    get_template_part('template-parts/blog-categories');
}
```

Comment: "why the is_front_page call is there" - so you could do just `if ( is_home() || is_archive() )` because `is_home()` would only be true on the Posts page (your "Blog" Page); however there's no harm checking for `is_front_page()` which would ensure the current page is not the "Start" Page which is the static site homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this instead

```
if (!is_front_page() && is_home()) {
    get_template_part('template-parts/blog-categories');
}
```

Explanation for the difference between front_page an home is here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/239838
if you set a page as a blog-page it is "home", in your case the landing-page is the so called "front_page". This is WordPress specific.

Comment: In my case the home page is the landing page and the /blog page is not the front page.

Comment: I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: @silviubogan, have you actually tried the code in this answer?

Comment: @SallyCJ I adapted the code to my own understanding and it does not work: this is the condition I used in the if statement: `!is_home() || is_front_page()`.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that I use a modified theme, and it was modified by a developer without good experience.

Comment: Try using the exact condition as in this answer: `!is_front_page() && is_home()` - and I believe that should work if you want to check whether the current page is the Posts page at `/blog`.

Comment: It works! Thanks! The final condition I use is `!is_front_page() && is_home() || is_archive()`. I still have to focus more to understand the role of is_front_page call in it.