# Last updated date function

Tags: functions, filters

I want to show the **"last updated date"** on the front of the post and page.
so I add the following code in the functions.php file.

```
function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) {
$u_time = get_the_time('U');
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U');
if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) {
$updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
$updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a');
$custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated" style="text-align:right">Last updated on '. $updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';
}
    $custom_content .= $content;
    return $custom_content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```

It works,but I don`t want to show **it** on my home page.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for your "home page" at the start of your function by using `is_home()` and/or `is_front_page()` and just return original content without date.  See [is_home vs is_front_page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/when-to-use-is-home-vs-is-front-page)

```
function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) {
  if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) return $content; //homepage return content without date

  // your original function code

}
```

Alterantively you could embes your add_filter in an if statement

Comment: ya!!!  it works !!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem !!

```
function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) {
if( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
    return $content;
}
if( is_page(array(1017,927))){  
    return $content;    
}
$u_time = get_the_time('U');
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U');
if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) {
$updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
$updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a');
$custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated">Last updated on '. $updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';  
}
    $custom_content .= $content;
    return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```